# Extracting GLM model estimates from package effects() in R

Tags: r, glm

I'm using GLM models to explain which effects are the most relevant to explain the occurrence of certain wildlife behaviours.

I'm using package `effects()`, which provides very useful plots. Below is a sample of code of one of the models tested:

```
> m7 <- glmer(cbind(Feeding,Standing_Foraging) ~ Day_Night+(1|ID) , data=GLM_df , family=binomial)
> summary(m7)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: cbind(Feeding, Standing_Foraging) ~ Day_Night + (1 | ID)
   Data: GLM_df

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   665.3    674.2   -329.6    659.3      141 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.09648 -0.60859 -0.02129  0.56377  3.07963 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID     (Intercept) 0.1461   0.3822  
Number of obs: 144, groups:  ID, 6

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error z value         Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    -1.13918    0.16406  -6.944 0.00000000000382 ***
Day_NightNight -0.15369    0.07525  -2.042           0.0411 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
Dy_NghtNght -0.206
```

And here are the plotted estimates with confidence intervals:

```
plot(allEffects(m7))
```

[image: plotted estimates]

My question is simple: How do I access the estimate values and respective confidence intervals plotted in the figure? I can't find any information on the forum so please, any help is appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
values <- effect("x", model)
summary(values)
```

`x` is the explanatory value you want information about
model is the name of your `glmer()` model.